# Deserialize LocalDate from version 1 to version 2

Tags: json.net, nodatime

Unfortunately we didn't add the [NodaTime.Serialization](https://nodatime.org/1.2.x/userguide/serialization) configuration to the [NEventStore](http://neventstore.org/) wiring when we started this project.

That means we have JSON documents in NEventStore like this.

Note. Simplified view. Not actually an event representation.

`dates.json`

```
{
    "$type": "NodatimeIssueTest.Product, NodatimeIssueTest",
    "FirstDate": {
        "$type": "NodaTime.LocalDate, NodaTime",
        "ticks": 12304224000000000,
        "calendar": "ISO"
    },
    "SecondDate": {
        "$type": "System.Nullable`1[[NodaTime.LocalDate, NodaTime]], mscorlib",
        "ticks": 12304224000000000,
        "calendar": "ISO"
    },
    "OtherDates": [
        {
            "$type": "NodaTime.LocalDate, NodaTime",
            "ticks": 12304224000000000,
            "calendar": "ISO"
        }
    ],
    "FirstDateTime": {
        "$type": "NodaTime.LocalDateTime, NodaTime",
        "ticks": 12304734100000000,
        "calendar": "ISO"
    },
    "FirstInstant": {
        "$type": "NodaTime.Instant, NodaTime",
        "ticks": 12304734100000000
    }
}
```

Instead of this

```
{
    "$type": "NodatimeIssueTest.Product, NodatimeIssueTest",
    "FirstDate": "2008-12-28",
    "SecondDate": "2008-12-28",
    "OtherDates": [
        "2008-12-28"
    ],
    "FirstDateTime": "2008-12-28T14:10:10",
    "FirstInstant": "2008-12-28T14:10:10Z"
}
```

Because of this we have hard time to upgrade to latest NodaTime package because we can't deserialize the json document anymore.

One solution would be to read all the NEventStore commits and serialize with correct NodaTime parsers. But if this could be avoided I would be happy.

Another option would be to do custom conversion and data binding.

But that requires low level Nodatime logic. Although we don't need to cover all calendars for example.

Comment: "I have this json serialized from Nodatime 1.4.7" - that wasn't created using NodaTime.Serialization.JsonNet though. That output is what you'd see if you used Json.NET to serialize Noda Time types without any specific conversions. Are you able to modify that JSON? I can probably write code to convert a document from that to the proper JSON format, but I don't know whether that will be useful to you.

Comment: "That output is what you'd see if you used Json.NET to serialize"
True. We use [NEventStore serializer](https://github.com/NEventStore/NEventStore/blob/master/src/NEventStore.Serialization.Json/JsonSerializer.cs).

To convert all events would be a challenge and something I would like to avoid if possible.

Comment: In that case you're somewhat stuck, to be honest - by ignoring the JSON serializer we provide, you're using the format of "a dump of all the public properties" - and that changed between Noda Time 1.x and 2.x. (I'm surprised it even worked for 1.x given that the types are immutable.) I'm not sure what to suggest - you could *potentially* write your own custom converter, if you can persuade Json.NET to use that when it sees `"$type": "NodaTime.LocalDate, NodaTime"`. I would suggest you change your example code though, given that it won't serialize to the data you've actually got.

Comment: (In particular, I'd expect that the sample you've given *would* work, because it uses `NodaTime.Serialization.JsonNet` for both serialization and deserialization. If that example genuinely isn't working for you, I'd happily look into that, but that's *not* the scenario you describe in the first half of the question.)

Comment: Likewise "When serializing the same data in 2.4.7 I get another structure than in 1.4.7" makes it sounds like the NodaTime version is all you've changed - whereas in reality you've changed from "not using NodaTime.Serialization.JsonNet" to "using NodaTime.Serialization.JsonNet", so you should absolutely expect a change in format.

Comment: Thanks for updating the question. "Another option would be to do custom conversion and data binding. But that requires low level Nodatime logic." - Well, not really. It would require a custom converter for each type, but I'd expect each converter to be simple. Rewriting the JSON (while using v1) would still be my recommendation if at all possible, as you wouldn't need to write nearly as much code. You'd just deserialize each document without the NodaTime serializer, then serialize it again with the serializer. I do understand that rewriting all documents may be tricky though.

Answer (score 1):

Solution with custom converters and binder for `dates.json` example in question

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization;
using NodaTime;
using NodaTime.Serialization.JsonNet;
using NUnit.Framework;

namespace NodatimeIssueTest
{
    [TestFixture]
    public class TestClass
    {
        [Test]
        public void Deserialize()
        {
            var serializer = new JsonSerializer();
            serializer.NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore;
            serializer.TypeNameHandling = TypeNameHandling.Objects;

            //Custom converters and binder
            serializer.Converters.Add(new NodaLocalDateConverter());
            serializer.Converters.Add(new NodaLocalDateTimeConverter());
            serializer.Converters.Add(new NodaInstantConverter());
            serializer.SerializationBinder = new CustomBinder();

            using (var sr = new StreamReader($@"{TestContext.CurrentContext.TestDirectory}\dates.json"))
            using (var reader = new JsonTextReader(sr))
            {
                var product = serializer.Deserialize<Product>(reader);
                Assert.AreEqual(new LocalDate(2008, 12, 28), product.FirstDate);
                Assert.AreEqual(new LocalDate(2008, 12, 28), product.SecondDate);
                Assert.AreEqual(new LocalDate(2008, 12, 28), product.OtherDates[0]);
                Assert.AreEqual(new LocalDateTime(2008, 12, 28, 14, 10, 10), product.FirstDateTime);
                Assert.AreEqual(Instant.FromUtc(2008, 12, 28, 14, 10, 10), product.FirstInstant);
            }
        }
    }

    public class Product
    {
        public LocalDate FirstDate { get; set; }
        public LocalDate? SecondDate { get; set; }
        public List<LocalDate> OtherDates { get; set; }

        public LocalDateTime FirstDateTime { get; set; }
        public Instant FirstInstant { get; set; }
    }

    public class NodaLocalDateConverter : JsonConverter
    {
        public override bool CanWrite => false;
        public override bool CanRead => true;

        public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
        {
            if (reader.TokenType == JsonToken.Null) return null;
            if (reader.TokenType == JsonToken.StartObject)
            {
                var custom = (CustomLocalDate) serializer.Deserialize(reader, typeof(CustomLocalDate));
                var dateTime = new DateTime(custom.Ticks, DateTimeKind.Utc).AddTicks(new DateTime(1970, 1, 1).Ticks);
                var local = LocalDate.FromDateTime(dateTime, CalendarSystem.Iso);

                return local;
            }

            return null;
        }

        public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
        {
            return objectType == typeof(LocalDate) || objectType == typeof(LocalDate?);
        }
    }

    public class NodaLocalDateTimeConverter : JsonConverter
    {
        public override bool CanWrite => false;
        public override bool CanRead => true;

        public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
        {
            if (reader.TokenType == JsonToken.Null) return null;
            if (reader.TokenType == JsonToken.StartObject)
            {
                var custom = (CustomLocalDateTime) serializer.Deserialize(reader, typeof(CustomLocalDateTime));
                var dateTime = new DateTime(custom.Ticks, DateTimeKind.Utc).AddTicks(new DateTime(1970, 1, 1).Ticks);
                var local = LocalDateTime.FromDateTime(dateTime, CalendarSystem.Iso);

                return local;
            }

            return null;
        }

        public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
        {
            return objectType == typeof(LocalDateTime) || objectType == typeof(LocalDateTime?);
        }
    }

    public class NodaInstantConverter : JsonConverter
    {
        public override bool CanWrite => false;
        public override bool CanRead => true;

        public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
        {
            if (reader.TokenType == JsonToken.Null) return null;
            if (reader.TokenType == JsonToken.StartObject)
            {
                var custom = (CustomInstant) serializer.Deserialize(reader, typeof(CustomInstant));
                var dateTime = new DateTime(custom.Ticks, DateTimeKind.Utc).AddTicks(new DateTime(1970, 1, 1).Ticks);
                var local = Instant.FromDateTimeUtc(dateTime);

                return local;
            }

            return null;
        }

        public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
        {
            return objectType == typeof(Instant) || objectType == typeof(Instant?);
        }
    }

    public class CustomBinder : DefaultSerializationBinder
    {
        public override Type BindToType(string assemblyName, string typeName)
        {
            switch (typeName)
            {
                case "NodaTime.LocalDate": return typeof(CustomLocalDate);
                case "System.Nullable`1[[NodaTime.LocalDate, NodaTime]]": return typeof(CustomLocalDate);

                case "NodaTime.LocalDateTime": return typeof(CustomLocalDateTime);
                case "System.Nullable`1[[NodaTime.LocalDateTime, NodaTime]]": return typeof(CustomLocalDateTime);

                case "NodaTime.Instant": return typeof(CustomInstant);
                case "System.Nullable`1[[NodaTime.Instant, NodaTime]]": return typeof(CustomInstant);

                default: return base.BindToType(assemblyName, typeName);
            }
        }
    }

    public class CustomLocalDate
    {
        [JsonProperty("ticks")] public long Ticks { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("calendar")] public string Calendar { get; set; }
    }

    public class CustomLocalDateTime
    {
        [JsonProperty("ticks")] public long Ticks { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("calendar")] public string Calendar { get; set; }
    }

    public class CustomInstant
    {
        [JsonProperty("ticks")] public long Ticks { get; set; }
    }
}
```